# Why and how Variational Inference underestimates variance?

Tags: variance, bayesian

I referred to the Quora link [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-and-when-does-mean-field-variational-Bayes-underestimate-variance) as well, but could not understand clearly.

Can anyone please help me understand why and how variational inference underestimates the variance of the true posterior distribution with some theory or mathematical calculations?

**[EDIT]: Adding my understanding of the Quora answer based on a visualization.**

[image]

The red line is p(x). The green line is q(x), the approximating distribution. The blue line is the KL divergence.

When q(x) is less than p(x), the KL divergence values at those points are negative. Those negative values will eventually help in reducing the overall KL divergence. So, variational inference does not care about reducing those. It cares about reducing KL divergence where q(x) is greater than p(x).

Since variational inference does not care about reducing KL divergence values where q(x) is less than p(x), the final q(x) can be of low variance as well. Hence, VI can underestimate variance.

Comment: The theory and calculations you seek are in the Quora answer as long as one knows what KL divergence is and how it is used in variational inference

Comment: Hi @NikosM. Could you please check if my understanding is correct? I have added it as an edit in the description above. Also, if possible, could you provide me some intuition regarding how the q(x) curve will ultimately turn out to be after variational inference?

Comment: I dont understand how you plot KL diveregence as it is independent of $x$ since it integrates over all $x$

Comment: @NikosM. I have removed the integration over x and considered the formula q(x)log(q(x)-q(x)log(p(x)) with the hope of understanding better.

Comment: I will see if later I can come up with an answer